# Installing Apache httpd 2.4 "--with-included-apr"

Tags: centos, httpd, apache-2.4

I'm trying to install Apache httpd 2.4.9 on a bare CentOS 6.5 server.

Using the command `./configure --prefix=/etc/httpd --with-included-apr`, the installation of httpd goes smoothly until it gets to the configuration of `apr-util`. It then provides the standard error when it can't find a suitable apr directory:

```
checking for APR... configure: error: the --with-apr parameter is incorrect. It must specify an install prefix, a build directory, or an apr-config file.
configure failed for srclib/apr-util
```

The first instance it checks for APR, it passes. The second when configuring `apr-util` fails. Currently I have both `apr` and `apr-util` in `/etc/httpd/httpd-2.4.9/srclib`.

Would moving the installation files from `/etc/httpd` (meaning the `httpd-2.4.9` directory) affect the install in any way? Perhaps moving `apr` and `apr-util` to another location entirely and then using the option `--with-apr` instead.

Comment: You probably need to place those in the build directory, not with your configuration files.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Something like `/usr/src/build` and put the `apr` folders in there?

Comment: The `srclib` directory from the exploded source tarball is correct, but you must rename the apr/apr-util so that there is no version number in the directory name. where you compile it shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

I have just run into the exact same issue, the final error message was deceiving. The actual error had occurred previously in the script and was permission denied. after giving execute to all .sh files in the build directories of both 'apr' and 'apr-util' it worked perfectly.

Comment: sounds like a bug report can be sent

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that my dir layout was this:

```
apr-1.7.0/
apr-util-1.6.1/
httpd-2.4.54/
```

...with symlinked dirs, i.e.:

```
httpd-2.4.54/srclib/apr -> ../../apr-1.7.0
httpd-2.4.54/srclib/apr-util ../../apr-util-1.6.1
```

They were definitely traversable and pointing to the right place as I could `ls` and `cd` into them. Failed with the same error you encountered.

I removed the symlinks and moved both dirs to the same path and then it was fine.